# How to run python script without writing command on cmd again and again

Tags: python

I am practicing python code and executing it through command line. each time i have to execute my python file i go to cmd and write

```
D:\PythonPractice>python myClass.py
```

Is there any standard and comfortable way available to execute python code quickly?

Comment: Like what would you expect? Something without python? note you are writing *2 words* PS - you can use up arrow to repeat last command. Then you write it once, and one button wooops - its there again

Comment: Maybe but something easy and convenient. Why should i bother to follow long step it take much time.

Comment: what editor are you using ?

Comment: I am using notepad++

Comment: Doesn't the Windows terminal let you recall the last command (eg with the up arrow), and allow you to modify it?

Comment: Um... You can press `up arrow` key on your keyboard to get the last command. So you just need `up arrow => enter`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use PyCharm Software by JetBrains (same company who developed Android studio and Kotlin language), it will help you in many ways .

- Run Python with single press of a button.
- Add modules easily just with some clicks.
- Debugging the code as smooth as possible.

It is Awesome, I am using it for past couple of months.

Answer (score 1):

If you are executing the same command, with no changes to arguments or anything, you can pack it in a .bat file (windows executable)

Name it something like `myscript.bat`

`D:\PythonPractice>python C:\path\to\myClass.py`

Put **full path** inside it. Now double click will do.

Comment: the path should be on the file

Comment: Yes, that's why I emphasized full path. I edited to make it more clear

Comment: python doesn't need a path, it cannot run with it

Answer (score 0):

you can change file association which controls what to do when invoking filename in command line. For instance, when you just type text filename in cmd, notepadd will be opened, for word docs Word or other document editor.

Have a look into following [link from google](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/change-file-associations-windows) or you can fiddle by yourself starting from *Control Panel > Control Panel Home > Default Programs > Set Associations. Select a file type in the list and click Change Program.*

Alternatively,you can use any of Python IDE (PyCharm,PyDev etc.) so you will be able to run directly scripts from editor.

Answer (score 0):

With Notepad++, you can also create a shortcut to be able to launch your python script :

Menu Run > Run (or press <kbd>F5</kbd>)

Choose the python .exe (default in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\python.exe`

Then add this code next to the path : "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"

This will allow to execute the current file

---

*example of command with Python 3.6 :*

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\python.exe" "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"
```

Then save the command, by assigning a shorcut key, it's better with a modifier like <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> (<kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd>)

Now you can launch any script with this shortcut.